# Using preg_match to capture text between tags with exception with PHP

Tags: php, html, preg-match, preg-match-all

From a `file_get_contents` I get the HTML code of an url.

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

Now I would like to capture the city name between `<span class="place ville">Ville : <span>` and `</span>`.

The HTML code is:

```
<span class="place ville">Ville : <span>City name</span></span>
```

So I'm using this:

```
preg_match('/<span class=\"place ville\">Ville : <span>(.+?)<\/span>/is', $html, $city);
$arr['city'] = $city[1];
```

It works.

---

But sometimes, the code is the following with a link:

```
<span class="place ville">Ville : <span><a href="https://example.com">City name</a></span></span>
```

In this case, the above code isn't working.

Do you know why ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should include the results you get when its "working" and "not working". Just to be clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a bit complicated, for which we'd just define two expressions and join them using a logical OR `|`:

```
<span class="place ville">Ville : <span><.+?>(.+?)<\/
```

and

```
<span class="place ville">Ville : <span>([^<]+)?<
```

#### RegEx

```
<span class="place ville">Ville : <span><.+?>(.+?)<\/|<span class="place ville">Ville : <span>([^<]+)?<
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RZxBRq/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/<span class="place ville">Ville : <span><.+?>(.+?)<\/|<span class="place ville">Ville : <span>([^<]+)?</m';
$str = '<span class="place ville">Ville : <span>City name</span></span>
    <span class="place ville">Ville : <span><a href="https://example.com">City name</a></span></span>
    <span class="place ville">Ville : <span>Århus</span></span>
    <span class="place ville">Ville : <span><a href="https://example.com">City name</a></span></span>
    ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $key => $city) {
    if ($city[1] == "") {
        echo $city[2] . "\n";
    } else {
        echo $city[1] . "\n";
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
City name
City name
Århus
City name
```

Comment: Hello Emma, thanks a lot for your help. Actually with all the HTML code of my page, I have too much match. Is there a way we can integrate the `Ville : ` to be more specific? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Emma, do you know why I have now this error with PHP: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4f78199f030738a013f0a9f5d6ea47e5c346e42? Thanks.

Comment: Hello Emma, the second one works well when the City hasn't `<a>`. But doesn't work if it has a `<a>`. Do you know why?

Comment: Thanks a lot Emma. You was very useful tonight. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, another option could be to use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and for example use [DOMXpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). Then from every [DOMElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) get the [textcontent](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent) or the [nodeValue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue):

```
$html = <<<HTML
<span class="place ville">Ville : <span>City name 1</span></span>
<span class="place ville">Ville : <span><a href="https://example.com">City name 2</a></span></span>
HTML;


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//span[contains(@class, 'place') and contains(@class, 'ville')]/span");

foreach ($nodeList as $n) {
    echo $n->textContent . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result

```
City name 1
City name 2
```

See a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/XEhSH)